# Rails model scope, updating from 3.2.12 to 4.2.11 - The scope body needs to be callable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am updating an application from ruby ~3 to ruby ~4 (Long story but it needs to be updated and cannot go beyond this due to being a legacy app from hell). The dev that made this has long since moved onto greener pastures and wasn't a big commenter.

The scope includes a reference to another model, records and a scope of that record is task. Throws an error that the scope body needs to be callable

Orginal:

```
scope :prod_review, includes(:records=>:task).active.where(
  Task.table_name + '.training_area_id = ? AND ' + Record.table_name + '.final_date is not null ',
  'msvs 003'
)
```

This throws an error on includes.

```
scope :prod_review, -> { includes(:records=>:task).active.where(
  Task.table_name + '.training_area_id = ? AND ' + Record.table_name + '.final_date is not null ',
  'msvs 003'
) }
```

Throws a syntax error pointing at the ->

```
 scope :production_review, includes(:records=>:task).active -> { where(
  Task.table_name + '.training_area_id = ? AND ' + QualificationRecord.table_name + '.final_date is not null ',
  'msvs 003'
 ) }
```

I know I need to update the it to a lambda, but haven't been able to get it working.

Remaking as a def:

I got an invalid SQL syntax. Ruby spits out:

```
def self.production_review, includes(:qualification_records=>:task).active.where(
  Task.table_name + '.training_area_id = ?,
  'msvs 003'
)

Generates this SQL:
# scope :ecr_production_review, includes(:qualification_records=>:task).active.where(
#  Task.table_name + '.training_area_id = ? AND ' + QualificationRecord.table_name + '. is not null ',
#  'msvs 003'
# )
SELECT [QualityDC].[dbmaster].[employees].* FROM [QualityDC].[dbmaster].[employees] WHERE (NOT status = 4 AND NOT status = 5) AND (QualityDC.dbmaster.Tasks.training_area_id = 'msvs 003') ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```

QualityDC.dbmaster.Tasks.training_area_id is supposed to be a join and looking for a column with the value 'msvs 003'

Comment: Updated with an edit

Comment: yeah the comma broke that particular portion, 

within one model, how would I query a table attached to another model with my where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Updated to use method calls to the corresponding models that returned the results of the joins